LDAP with Gitea doesn't find user
I have some troubles with configuring LDAP into app.ini file. After putting all the configuration attributes, I try to access with my username, which is into our LDAP directory, but with no success.
Here is the configuration I used (company name replaced with "ourcompany" and the password is not the real one):
[ldap]
NAME = LDAP
HOST = ldap.ourcompany.com
PORT = 389
SECURITY_PROTOCOL = unencrypted
SKIP_VERIFY = false
BIND_DN = cn=ldap,dc=ourcompany,dc=com
BIND_PASSWORD = ixVziIrc8T 
USER_SEARCH_BASE = dc=users,dc=ourcompany,dc=com
USER_FILTER = (&(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)(uid=%[1]s))
ADMIN_FILTER = (memberOf=cn=admin,dc=ourcompany,dc=com)
ATTRIBUTE_USERNAME = uid
ATTRIBUTE_NAME = cn
ATTRIBUTE_MAIL = mail
SEARCH_PAGE_SIZE = 100
SEARCH_TIMEOUT = 60
ATTRIBUTE_IN_BIND = true

I tried to log in on the Web UI without success. So, I added the following sections:
[auth]
enable_ldap = true

[auth.ldap]
… as above, under the [ldap] declaration …

Again, no success.
For debugging purposes, I modified the logging section:
[log]
MODE = file,console,traceconsole
LEVEL = debug

[log.file]
LEVEL = debug
ROOT_PATH = /var/log/gitea

[log.traceconsole]
MODE = console
LEVEL = trace
EXPRESSION = ldap

This is the error I got while trying to log in:
2024/09/13 08:36:07 .../context_response.go:70:HTML() [D] Template: user/auth/signin 2024/09/13 08:36:07 ...ers/web/auth/auth.go:231:SignInPost() [I] Failed authentication attempt for z.rossi from 10.10.11.64:8448: user does not exist [uid: 0, name: z.rossi] 2024/09/13 08:36:07 ...eb/routing/logger.go:102:func1() [I] router: completed POST /user/login for 10.10.11.64:8448, 200 OK in 15.0ms @ auth/auth.go:196(auth.SignInPost)

Gitea runs with an user created specifically for this, called git. The /etc/gitea/app.ini file has 664 as permissions, with git:git as owner.
The service file has git configured as user too (note: the variables here are because this is part of a script):
[Unit] 
Description=Gitea Ourcompany
After=network.target 
[Service] 
RestartSec=2s 
Type=simple 
User=git 
Group=git 
WorkingDirectory=$GITEA_WORK_DIR/ 
ExecStart=$GITEA_WORK_DIR/gitea web --config $GITEA_CONF_DIR/app.ini 
Restart=always 
Environment=USER=git HOME=$MY_HOME GITEA_WORK_DIR=$GITEA_WORK_DIR
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

(the $GITEA_CONF_DIR is /etc/gitea/).
I checked with the ldapsearch command, using all the filters I put in the ldap. It does return my user:
ldapsearch -w -H ldap://ldap.ourcompany.com -w "ixVziIrc8T" -b "dc=users,dc=ourcompany,dc=com" -D "cn=ldap,dc=ourcompany,dc=com" "(uid=z.rossi)

(I replaced my real name with Zombie Rossi)

 extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <dc=users,dc=armundia,dc=com> with scope subtree
# filter: (uid=z.rossi)
# requesting: ALL
#

# z.rossi, users.ourcompany.com
dn: uid=z.rossi,dc=users,dc=ourcompany,dc=com
objectClass: person
objectClass: posixAccount
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: top
cn: Zombie Rossi
description: Zombie Rossi
sn: Zombie Rossi
uidNumber: 500
gidNumber: 500
homeDirectory: /home/z.rossi
mail: z.rossi@ourcompany.com
uid: z.rossi
loginShell: /bin/bash

# search result
search: 2
result: 0 Success

# numResponses: 2
# numEntries: 1

I tried with the gitea admin command and it didn’t work (company name replaced with "ourcompany" and password replaced with a random string, as previously done in this post):
gitea admin auth add-ldap --config "/etc/gitea/app.ini" --name "Our Company LDAP" --security-protocol "unencrypted" --host "ldap.ourcompany.com" --port 389 --user-search-base "dc=users,dc=ourcompany,dc=com" --bind-dn "cn=ldap,dc=ourcompany,dc=com" --bind-password "ixVziIrc8T" --user-filter "(&(objectClass=person)(uid=%s))" --email-attribute "mail"

the cn=ldap is necessary. It was created specifically and it works in our other platforms that make use of LDAP.
I had some success in logging in by adding the flag --attributes-in-bind "true" with update-ldap … But I don’t have administrative permissions, once inside.
What am I getting wrong?
We are using OpenLDAP.
